# pymongo get all documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So we can easily get all of the docs in this format:

```
stuff = []
for thing in db.stuff.find(projection = {"name":1}):
    stuff.append(thing["name"])
```

But this is miserably slow.  I can possibly add a meta store which stores a complete list of names of my things; but it would be nice if I could just get a big batch of stuff back.

I can't seem to find documentation on this.

Comment: Do you use an index on "name"?

Comment: I have a descending unique index there.  There are 5749 documents.